# Changing woocommerce pagination structure

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have searched all over for solutions, but I can't find one that actually helps me.

On my store, when you hover over a woocommerce pagination link, the pagination format looks like this: `mycategory/page/2`.
However, once you click on it the URL in the address bar shows `mycategory/?_paged=2`.

(It almost seems as if the one redirects to the other, which means the way the pagination is linked needs to change.)

I want the pagination to be linked the same as the actual pagination URLs (`mycategory/?_paged=2`)

I have searched through the woocommerce template files but I can't figure out how to change it. I think it must be changed in this code, but I can't seem to figure it out. Is it the $format variable that needs to be edited?

```
$total   = isset( $total ) ? $total : wc_get_loop_prop( 'total_pages' );
$current = isset( $current ) ? $current : wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' );
$base    = isset( $base ) ? $base : esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) );
$format  = isset( $format ) ? $format : '';

if ( $total <= 1 ) {
    return;
}
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
    echo paginate_links(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_pagination_args',
            array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'base'      => $base,
                'format'    => $format,
                'add_args'  => false,
                'current'   => max( 1, $current ),
                'total'     => $total,
                'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                'type'      => 'list',
                'end_size'  => 3,
                'mid_size'  => 3,
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just to check is your Permalink setting setup to Plain or Post name? Also just to check the URL structure that you want is "mycategory/?_paged=2" and not "mycategory/page/2"

Comment: `_paged` is not a standard WordPress pagination query string - did you mean `paged`? And to me, seems like a theme issue, but have you tried deactivating all plugins, except WooCommerce itself?